# What is the C# equivalent code for C programming statement?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

What is the `C#` Equivalent code for C Programming statement:

```
#define xtime(x) ((x<<1) ^ (((x>>7) & 1) * 0x1b))
```

Comment: Did you find this at an obfuscation contest?  Don't write code like that.

Comment: This is objectively awful code. Taking into consideration for multiple expansions for `x`, I don't know that there there is a C# equivalent. Ignoring that, however, the expression would compile as is, I think, depending on the type of `x`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `#define` in C# is different from C and C++, you should use method call instead.

```
private int xtime(int x)
{
    return (x << 1) ^ (((x >> 7) & 1) * 0x1b);
}
```